# Is it possible to make a dual-mode, multi-band laser?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, gas, experimental-technique, photon-emission

Understanding [how N2 and CO2 gas lasers work](https://www.worldoflasers.com/lasertypes-gas.htm),

Is it possible to make a gas laser (i.e. with the right gas mix and excitation source) that:

1. has more than one mode of operation,
2. emits light in more than one band (Near-IR and UV, in this case)?

Comment: Another detail I am curious about is the role of Helium in both setups; how does it affect the energy gain coefficient of each lasing gas as its concentration varies?  Principle-based speculation is fine, I'm not trying to mooch data from anyone.

Comment: Probably. The multi-mode question seems relatively easy because without careful optical design most lasers tend to operate in multiple modes anyway. That's more of a question about how we design the resonator. Whether we can get this to work as a stable device is another question. Did you do a literature search for such devices? What did it turn up? Just curious.

Comment: I am voting to reopen since whether it is possible for a laser to operate simultaneously in multiple modes or wavelengths is an experimental laser physics question, not an engineering question about laser applications. The answer is yes, but the details cannot be squeezed into a comment.  For example, gas [ion lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_laser) can lase at multiple visible wavelengths producing a ["white" laser beam](https://www.photonlexicon.com/laserfaq/laserarg.htm#argwse4). I don't know if any do NIR and UV simultaneously.

Comment: @FlatterMann The link included in the question is most of what I could turn up in one source; there is, from my cursory search for it, a dearth of information on how this can work in a hybridized design, i.e. combine two working designs into one.  I chose N2 and CO2 because they both use common gases as the lasing medium, both use helium (for different purposes) and are capable of power outputs beyond the milliwatt range.